# Calling c++ method in C# project

Tags: c#

i have a vc   compiled library. There is method, that i need to call in the c# project . help me to find out the correct way  to invoke the vc   method in my C# project

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just create a reference to `C/C++` project from your `C#` project.

There are several options to achieve that:

1. Use [Pinvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. Compile your library to [Managed C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11634/Managed-C-Learn-by-Example-Part-1)
3. Generate COM object from that library and *after* import in your `C#` project.